# Is there a way to input column names without quotes and use that as a subset in another function in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I am trying to highlight duplicates using:

```
print(df.duplicated(subset = column_subset, keep=False))
```

I want users of this script to input the column_subset using:

```
column_subset = input("Enter list of columns for group by:")
```

I want users to enter the column names as follows: `val1,val2,val3`

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
column_subset = []

# number of elements as input 
n = int(input("Enter number of elements : ")) 

# iterating till the range 
for i in range(0, n): 
    ele = int(input()) 
    column_subset.append(ele) # adding the element
```

You can make the user enter input one-by-one and append those elements in a list. Use this list in your duplicated command.

### If you want user to enter a list of col names, simply do this:

```
column_subset = input("Enter list of columns for group by:")
column_subset = column_subset.split(',')
```

Comment: I would want the user to enter the actual column names. Is there a way to do that?